# How do merge two lists into an array, so that I don't have to hard code it

Tags: python, arrays, list

For ex, if I have the following two arrays.

```
x = [1,3,5]
y = [2,4,6]
```

I don't want to hard code like the following to display the output.
Because if I do this, then there is no point of having `x` and `y` from above.

```
arr = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
```

How can I just write a statement, which just makes an array recognizing that each index of `x` corresponds to the same index of `y`.

So, `x = 1` is `y = 2` and so on.

Answer (score 4):

You should use the [`zip` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) and convert it to a list like this:

```
>>> array = list(zip(x, y))
[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
```

This will create a list of tuples. Do note, you are still able to perform normal indexing operations and such on tuples, like lists. If you really want sublists instead of tuples, then you should be doing this:

```
>>> array = [list(item) for item in list(zip(x, y))]
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

Comment: You should note the difference in behavior of `zip()` between Python 2 and 3.

Answer (score 3):

```
arr = [list(item) for item in zip(x,y)]
```

Comment: Thanks!! You saved me a lot of time.

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.

Answer (score -1):

If you are fine with individual couplings being tuples, here's another flavor:

```
x = [1,3,5]
y = [2,4,6]

print zip(*[x,y]) #prints [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
```

Of course you can modify it to be:

```
a = zip(*[x,y])
b = [ list(n) for n in a ] #gives: [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
```